# Converting a Trigger into a Class Auto follow in chatter

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, after-trigger

I am very new to Apex, and was hoping that someone could help me. I do have a trigger in place, but would like to convert it into a Class. I will be calling this class from a new trigger, but I lack the coding skills. Here is the trigger, could someone help me convert it into a class?

```
trigger DevelopmentOwnerChatterSubscription on Story__c (after insert, after update) {

    List<EntitySubscription> stEntitySubList = new List<EntitySubscription>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Story__c st:trigger.new){

        EntitySubscription stEntity = new EntitySubscription();
        stEntity.ParentId = st.Id;
        stEntity.SubscriberId = st.Owner__c;
        stEntitySubList.add(stEntity);      
        }

        insert stEntitySubList;
}
    if(trigger.isUpdate){

    List<EntitySubscription> stEntitySubListUpdate = new List<EntitySubscription>();
    List<Story__c> stList = new List<Story__c>();

    for (Story__c st:Trigger.new) {
        Story__c oldStory = Trigger.oldMap.get(st.ID);
        if (st.Owner__c != oldStory.Owner__c) {
            stList.add(st);
        }
    }

delete[select ID from EntitySubscription where ParentId IN :stList];

    for(Story__c st : stList){
        EntitySubscription e = new EntitySubscription();
        e.ParentId = st.Id;
        e.SubscriberId = st.Owner__c;
        stEntitySubListUpdate.add(e);
    }
    insert stEntitySubListUpdate;   
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are very new to Apex, you may find Trailhead a more forgiving and comprehensive learning path.

Comment: I am definitely working through Trailhead, but wanted to resolve this issue as well.

Comment: Take a look at [Bulk State Transition](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Bulk_State_Transition) from Apex Design Patterns. It has a good example for what you are asking

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking. Convert a trigger into a class? You mean abstract the trigger code into a class to clean it up? Or get rid of the trigger and put the code someplace else to be used manually?

Comment: I am trying to make some changes on my triggers, based on best practices. For example, I am trying to have only one trigger per object, which is why I would like to move my trigger to be executed as a Class. For that purpose, I created a trigger handler class, which calls different methods. My goal is for the trigger above to be replaced as a method, which my trigger would invoke through a trigger handler class.  Thanks for the documentation Oleksiy.